# Creating post landslide simulation using ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, simulation

How do I create a simulation for post landslide with ArcScene?

It should able to show xyz plus velocity and thickness of debris at different time.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Ensure your data has time and enable time in layer properties to animate.

Comment: i am totally new to arcgis or arcscene. i have no idea how to start. hope to have some guide to show each steps. thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Did you do the animation displayed in your OP?  If so, what about it does not meet your needs?

Comment: just searched the image to be a sample what i am looking for or similar.. i cant find any guidelines from internet so i have ask here to seek for help...